# Change font size without Change UITextView attributedText

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I try to change a font size in my UITextView and every time I change the attributedText was restore to default.

with this I make the middle test bold :

```
str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:string];

[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];
```

before: that was bold font in the middle.

[image]

after :all the text bold

[image]

I want that after the size change the bold stay where he be.

Edit :

I try with this two ways :

1)

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:currentTextViewEdit.text];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName  value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, currentTextViewEdit.text.length)];
        currentTextViewEdit.attributedText = attributedString;
```

2)

```
currentTextViewEdit.font = [UIFont   fontWithName:currentTextViewEdit.font.fontName size:textSize];
```

Comment: How do you change the font size?

Comment: currentTextViewEdit.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentTextViewEdit.font.fontName size:textSize];

Comment: Not tested, but: http://pastebin.com/wFGhK5W1 ?

Comment: If it works, could you validate my answer to help people with the same issue to see the solution clearly and not in comment?

Comment: you got it (-: thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported by @matt:
`aUITextView.font` => change on `text` property (plain text)
So switching between `attributedText` and `text` like you're doing is causing the issue.

On your other solution:
Bold effect is inside the `NSFontAttributeName`, it's the Font value. So if you replace it by a common font, that will remove the "bold" effect. Same for italic.

So a way to do it (not tested, by according to you it's working):
• Save the `attributedText` (to remember the "effects", like bold in your case)
• Save the cursor position (I didn't test, so I don't know where would go the cursor afterward)
• Change the font size keeping the previous font (may be bold of normal) to the attributed string
• Update the `attributedText`
• Replace the cursor

You can use a Category on `UITextView` with a method `-(void)changeFontSize:(float)newFontSize;` and then you call `self` instead of `currentTextViewEdit`.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[currentTextViewEdit attributedText] mutableCopy];

//Save the cursor/selection
NSRange cursorRange = [currentTextViewEdit selectedRange];

//Apply to update the effects on new text typed by user?
[currentTextViewEdit setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[[currentTextViewEdit font] fontName] size:newFontSize]];

//Update the font size
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])
                             options:0
                          usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                              UIFont *currentfont = (UIFont*)value;
                              UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[currentfont fontName] size:newFontSize];
                              [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                          }];
[currentTextViewEdit setAttributedText:attributedString];

//To restaure the cursor/selection
[currentTextViewEdit setSelectedRange:cursorRange];
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what your question is. Your observation, however, is *exactly correct*: If you are using an attributed text (`attributedText`), then if you change a pure text feature of the text view (like `font`), it resets the attributed text. That's because you're *not supposed to do that*. You *must not* attempt to combine attributed text features with plain text features. Use the plain text features (like `font`) only if you are using a plain `text`.

If, for example, you want to change the font when you're using attributed text, change the font *of the attributed text*. To do so, pull out the `attributedText`, put it into an NSMutableAttributedString, make your change, and assign it back into the `attributedText`.

Comment: You haven't made any change that changes anything about my answer. I stand by it.