# UITextView attributed text not working when using custom font

Tags: ios, uitextview, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using `UITextView` and I'm setting its font and attributed text by code.

**Case 1:**  *Custom-font - YES* , *attribtued text*- NO

[image]

The textView text is displayed in custom font.

I want the attribtued text with custom font i.e **Message :** in this case shold be bolded.

**Case 2:**  *Custom-font - YES* , *attribtued text*- YES

[image]

Only the attribtued text(Bold text) is displayed in custom font.

The code I have is:

```
- (void)loadTextView
{
    _textView.text=NSLocalizedString(@"more_info_text",nil);
    _textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"BurbankSmall-Medium" size:16];

    NSRange rangeBold  = [_textView.text rangeOfString:@"Examples of invalid characters:"];
    NSRange rangeBold2 = [_textView.text rangeOfString:@"Restricted text:"];
    NSRange rangeBold3 = [_textView.text rangeOfString:@"Message :"];

    UIFont *fontText = [self boldFontWithFont:_textView.font];
    NSDictionary *dictBoldText = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontText, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

    NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text];
    [mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold];
    [mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold2];
    [mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold3];

    [_textView setAttributedText:mutAttrTextViewString];

    _textView.editable=NO;
    _textView.selectable=NO;
}

- (UIFont *)boldFontWithFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    UIFontDescriptor * fontD = [font.fontDescriptor
                                fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
    return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:16];
}
```

When I comment the line `setAttributedText:mutAttrTextViewString` , evrything is displayed in custom font. When I uncomment it, only the attribtued text is showed in custom font, and rest is showed in default font.

Why is this happening ? If this is not possible I'm thinking to include html content as the attributed text, but I want to consider that as an option in worst case.

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BurbankSmall-Medium" size:16]}];`? If you log `mutAttrTextViewString` with your current code, you should see that it doesn't have the font for the rest of the text (where you didn't put the bold font) and doesn't have to get by default the font set in `_textView` for *PLAIN text*.

Comment: I did set the font for the text view , and why the mutAttrTextViewString is not taking the textView font ? @Larme

Comment: I didn't say that it should replace your WHOLE use of `mutAttrTextViewString`. It's just that line `NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text];`. For the rest, you keep calling `[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold];` and the two other lines.

Comment: For the same reasons given there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064762/change-font-size-without-change-uitextview-attributedtext (see *@matt's* comment). `font` property of `UITextView` is for it's `text` property (as commonly said plain text), and not for its `attributedText` property.

Comment: Do you want to put that comment as an answer ? @Larme It worked. It is quite strange that we need to specify the attributes again for the mutable string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064762/change-font-size-without-change-uitextview-attributedtext).
The main issue is that `font` (`UIFont`) property of `UITextView` is to be applied for its `text` (`NSString`) property (also named "plain text") and not for the `attributedText` (`NSAttributedString`).

So you have to applied the "normal" font effect to your `NSAttributedString` yourself.

So just replace:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text];
```

with:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BurbankSmall-Medium" size:16]}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the font outside of the attributed text, try setting all the font changes at once inside of the attributed string:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BurbankSmall-Medium" size:16] range:NSMakeRange(0, _textView.text.length)];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold2];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold3];

[_textView setAttributedText:mutAttrTextViewString];
```