# Increasing text size of textView leads to smaller text | Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, font-size, text-size

I tried to build a textView with two buttons to in/decrease the size of the text. I used:

```
textView.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 50)
```

But no matter which number I set for the size, the text always becomes the same size (around 11) when calling the method.

Why is that? Could you help me with that?

Comment: Do you use `attributedText` property of `textView`? If that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120535/uitextview-attributed-text-not-working-when-using-custom-font/37132592#37132592

Comment: Actually no. I am new to Swift, could you help me, how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to do something you said, you can make your own category like this:

```
extension UITextView {
    func increaseFontSize () {
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font!.fontName, size: self.font!.pointSize+4)!
    }
}
```

To use it just import it like this:

```
textview.increaseFontSize()
```

This will increase your text by 4.